# No puedo instalar composer en mi MacOS Catalina. zsh: illegal hardware instruction php composer-setup.php

Tags: php, laravel, macos

[image: Terminal]

Al poner el comando que sale en la pagina oficial me sigue saliendo el mismo error de zsh:

> illegal hardware instruction  php composer-setup.php

mi version de php es 8.0.21

MacOS Catalina

Alguien que me pudiera ayudar a resolverlo? Gracias.

Comment: Te sirve lo que sugieren [aquí](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4202) ?

Comment: No, al parecer ahí el problema es al momento de actualizarlo, en cambio el mio es al instalarlo, ya lo intente por homebrew e igualmente me sale el mismo error

Comment: Intentaste con el script que menciona en la página oficial? [link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-composer-programmatically.md)

Comment: Ya lo conseguí, muchas gracias